# iOS Localized strings not working

Tags: ios, localizable.strings

I check my Localized files and they are free of errors.
I'm using the library https://github.com/d0ping/DBAttachmentPickerController and looks like the source of my problems.

I have the following error:

2017-06-23 15:50:31.056756+0200 MyApp[5116:1989916] No localized string for 'file_infected' in 'DBAttachmentPickerController'

DBAttachmentPickerController belongs to the library that I had installed with cocoapods and 'file_infected' is a string that belongs to my project Localized files.

Comment: You did what James suggested?

Answer (score 3):

I've had this trouble using a library in the past.

I gather both your project and the library you are using will also contain a `Localizable.strings`. During build time, only one of these files will be copied (or one will overwrite the other). This leads to some interesting intermittent bugs where sometimes your strings are translated, and sometimes they are not!

The most robust solution, though not the fastest is to rename your strings file and use the `tableName` parameter of `NSLocalizedString`. e.g. for a file named "RicardosProject.strings", I believe the tableName should be "RicardosProject"

```
    func NSLocalizedString(
    key: String,
    tableName: String? = default,
    bundle: NSBundle = default,
    value: String = default,
    #comment: String) -> String
```